# Azure terraform deployment issue - unknown addon_profile

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-log-analytics

i am trying to deploy kubernetes cluster with OMS monitoring enabled with below code snippet.

```
addon_profile {
  oms_agent {
    enabled                    = true
    log_analytics_workspace_id = "${var.omswsid}"
    }
}

network_profile {
  network_plugin = "azure"
}
```

when i am running terraform plan i am getting below errors.

```
Error: module.k8s.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s: : invalid or unknown key: addon_profile
Error: module.k8s.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s: : invalid or unknown key: network_profile
```

Let me know your inputs. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should update you terraform modules to the latest version, as the code snippets seem to be fine

Comment: I am running latest version of terraform. Below is the output.

`code`    Terraform v0.11.10 
         + provider.azurerm v1.5.0
         + provider.null v1.0.0
         + provider.tls v1.2.0
`

Answer (score 0):

Removed version dependency from Provider file. 
Updated modules using below commands solved my issue.

```
terraform init -upgrade
terraform get -update
```